# How can I get the help documentation to work in WebApi2 when using IHttpActionResult?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I want to take advantage of the automated documentation features of WebApi2 as well IHttpActionResult. Therefore I would like to change the following piece of code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets specified User 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">User Id</param>
/// <returns>The user</returns>
public UserModel Get(int id)
{
    UserModel result = new UserModel()
    {
        ErrorLevel = "Warning",
        ErrorMessage = "Not Implemented yet!"
    };
    User u = new User() { Id = 1, ADUserName = "nfindlater", DefaultRoutingGroupId = 1 };
    result.Data = u;

    var helper = new UrlHelper(Request);
    result.Url = helper.Link("User", new { userId = 1 });

    return result;
}
```

To

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets specified User 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">User Id</param>
    /// <returns>The user</returns>
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        UserModel result = new UserModel()
        {
            ErrorLevel = "Warning",
            ErrorMessage = "Not Implemented yet!"
        };
        User u = new User() { Id = 1, ADUserName = "nfindlater", DefaultRoutingGroupId = 1 };
        result.Data = u;

        var helper = new UrlHelper(Request);
        result.Url = helper.Link("User", new { userId = 1 });

        return Ok<UserModel>(result);
    }
```

But when I do this I loose part of the automatically generated api documentation under /Help/Api/GET-2013-12-05-user-id.

Here is the part of the documentation that is lost:

#### Response body formats

application/json, text/json
        
            **Sample:**

{
  "url": "sample string 1",
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "adUserName": "sample string 2",
    "name": "sample string 3",
    "defaultRoutingGroupId": 4
  },
  "errorLevel": "sample string 2",
  "errorMessage": "sample string 3"
}

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can decorate the action with the "ResponseType" attribute and HelpPage would pick this up to generate the sample...

Example : [ResponseType(typeof(UserModel)]

Comment: Just curious -- How did you know that? Where is the full list of possible options located?

Comment: The source code for WebAPI2 is available here (http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) and you'll find the ApiDescription functionality and the ResponseType attribute in the System.Web.Http project in the Description folder. You can explore this to gain a deeper understanding of how this all works.